# Need help creating a function and calling a function in a function

Tags: python, function

I'm new to programming/Python.  I'm trying to create a function that will add a word to a list. I tried to use a while loop to add ask if the user wants to add another word.  If the user inputs 'y' or 'Y' I want to run the function again.  If the user inputs anything else, I want the function to return the list.  When I run the function, it continues to run the function again no matter what is input.  Please help.  Thanks

```
def add_list():
    x = []
    first_list = raw_input('Please input a word to add to a list ')
    x.append(first_list)
    response = raw_input('Would you like to enter another word ')
    while response == 'y' or 'Y':
        add_list()
    else:
        return x
```

Answer (score 4):

```
while response == 'y' or 'Y':
```

Should be

```
while response == 'y' or response == 'Y':
```

or better yet:

```
while response in ('y', 'Y'):
```

---

Here's why what you did doesn't work. Each line below is equivalent.

```
while response == 'y' or 'Y'
while (response == 'y') or ('Y')
while (response == 'y') or True
while True
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I revised the while portion to what you suggested and I still doesn't work correctly.  It continues to loop if I input anything other than 'y' or 'Y'.  Am I missing something?

Comment: @user1816629: Should be `if`, not `while`

Answer (score 1):

Just make the list a parameter you pass to the function:

```
x = []
add_list(x)
```

With add_list(x)

```
def add_list(x):
  first_list = raw_input('Please input a word to add to a list ')
  x.append(first_list)
  response = raw_input('Would you like to enter another word ')
  while response in ('y', 'Y'):
    add_list(x)
  else:
    return
```

Comment: I don't think this is the problem OP mentioned.

Comment: You are right on the infinite loop part but his current return is still a problem which he'll be facing once he solved the infinite loop. Edited the loop condition according to Eric's answer.